# Rate of change when the particle $t = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that temperature at a point $(x, y, z)$ in $R^3$ is $T(x,y.z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$. A particle moves so that at time $t$ its location is given by $(x,y,z)=(t,t^2,t^3)$. Find that temperature at the point occupied by the particle at $t=\frac{1}{2}$. What is the rate of change of temperature at the particle when $t=\frac{1}{2}$

My approach:
I thought of taking the derivative of $t$ to get: $(x, y, z)'=(1, 2t, 3t^2)$ and then placing $t=\frac{1}{2}$ which is then equal to $(1, 1, \frac{3}{4})$

Where to go next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that
$$\begin{cases}
T(x,y,z) &=x^2+y^2+z^2\\
(x,y,z) &= (t,t^2,t^3)
\end{cases}$$ you get the temperature at time $t$, namely

$$\mathcal T(t)=t^2+t^4+t^6.$$ Therefore
$\mathcal T\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{25}{64}$ and $\mathcal T^\prime\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=2t+4t^3+6t^5=\frac{27}{32}$.

Comment: This cleared my doubts!